# Website is already referencing the assembly System.Configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, configurationmanager

I am trying to add System.Configuration as a reference but get the message

```
Website is already referencing the assembly System.Configuration
```

I aneed this however to access ConfigurationManager.

How can I solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: Did you try by rebuilding the application and are you able to see the `System.Configuration` in the References of the WebApp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a reference you only need to put a `using` statement in the top of your .cs-file:

```
using System.COnfiguration;
```